# MySQL query broke after adding join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, content-management-system

I have a query that loads data for a loop in my CMS to display posts. Everything was working fine in the vote columns until I left-joined the comment column. Comments display OK, but the totalvote, upvote and downvote counts are wildly off. Let me know if you need to see the tables.

```
SELECT
count(DISTINCT comment.comment ) AS Comment,
idea.dateofcreation AS timestamp, 
idea.userId AS userId,
idea.id AS ID,
idea.text AS Idea,
page.permalink AS Permalink,
user.name AS Username,
COUNT(CASE WHEN votelog.vote !="" THEN 1 END) AS 'totalvotes',
COUNT(CASE WHEN votelog.vote = '1' THEN 1 END) AS 'upvote',
COUNT(CASE WHEN votelog.vote = '-1' THEN 1 END) AS 'downvote'
FROM idea
LEFT JOIN votelog ON idea.id = votelog.ideaid
LEFT JOIN user ON idea.userId = user.id
LEFT JOIN page ON idea.id = page.ideaid
LEFT join comment ON comment.ideaid = idea.id 
GROUP BY idea.id
ORDER BY totalvotes DESC
```

Comment: Because the comments probably has many records in it to your one in your user/page table so your counts are getting added for every record in the comments table vs the one you had before.  Try testing with just one page/user  in your where clause and you will be able to see it

Comment: "
Because the comments probably has many records in it to your one in your user/page table so your counts are getting added for every record in the comments table vs the one you had before" Well the `DISTINCT` in the `COUNT` should counteract that (normally) @Brad .. So he can do `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN votelog.vote !="" THEN 1 END) AS 'totalvotes',`.. But it is better to use a delivered table (subquery) approach like Gordon Linoff's answer

Comment: The count is not the issue he is saying it is with the upvote/downvotes that he is having the issues with and he is not accounting for the comments being added in that part of the logic.

Comment: notice what i said @Brad "@Brad .. "So he can do COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN votelog.vote !="" THEN 1 END) AS 'totalvotes',"

Comment: Sorry I replied before you finished editing the comment with the details you are pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you decided to join the table `comments` **only to count how many comments** are there.

But by doing so, you are now producing multiple rows, one per comment, and that gets all other counts off.

I would suggest using a scalar subquery to count the comments, and removing the join. Something like:

```
SELECT
(select count(DISTINCT comment) from comment c where c.ideaid = idea.id) AS Comment,
idea.dateofcreation AS timestamp, 
idea.userId AS userId,
idea.id AS ID,
idea.text AS Idea,
page.permalink AS Permalink,
user.name AS Username,
COUNT(CASE WHEN votelog.vote !="" THEN 1 END) AS 'totalvotes',
COUNT(CASE WHEN votelog.vote = '1' THEN 1 END) AS 'upvote',
COUNT(CASE WHEN votelog.vote = '-1' THEN 1 END) AS 'downvote'
FROM idea
LEFT JOIN votelog ON idea.id = votelog.ideaid
LEFT JOIN user ON idea.userId = user.id
LEFT JOIN page ON idea.id = page.ideaid
GROUP BY idea.id
ORDER BY totalvotes DESC
```

Comment: I get an error that says "subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: My bad. I forgot the `COUNT()` in the second line. Fixed.

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly. I'm going to study it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one comment.  So, aggregate before joining:

```
SELECT c.num_comments,
       i.dateofcreation AS timestamp, i.userId AS userId, i.id AS ID, i.text AS Idea,
       p.permalink AS Permalink, p.name AS Username,
       SUM( vl.vote <> '' ) AS totalvotes,
       SUM( vl.vote = 1 ) AS upvote,
       SUM( vl.vote = -1 ) AS downvote
FROM idea i LEFT JOIN
     votelog vl
     ON i.id = vl.ideaid LEFT JOIN
     user u
     ON i.userId = u.id LEFT JOIN
     page p
     ON i.id = p.ideaid LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.ideaid, COUNT(*) as num_comments
      FROM comment c
      GROUP BY c.ideaid
     ) c
     ON c.ideaid = i.id 
GROUP BY c.num_comments,
       i.dateofcreation i.userId, i.id, i.text,
       p.permalink, p.name
ORDER BY totalvotes DESC;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.
- It is a good practice to include all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` (and more recent versions of MySQL tend to enforce this).
- I assume the votes are numbers.  Compare them to numbers, not to strings.
- MySQL has a nice shorthand for counting the number of times a boolean expression is true.

Comment: Maybe it's because of all the alias's but I am confused. I like how you used the sum function. Can you post that without all the alias's, or just explain how I'm supposed to define them. It doesn't run, not sure if it's supposed to run like that.

Comment: @badcarbine . . . The aliases should make the query *easier* to write and to read, not harder.